# Почему у std::bitset нет конструктора для std::string_view?

Tags: c++

Почему у `std::bitset` нет конструктора для `std::string_view`?

Comment: а почему у него должен быть такой конструктор? что вы от него ожидаете?

Comment: @user7860670 того же, что и от конструктора с обычной строкой

Comment: Можете отправить свое предложение в [Российскую рабочую группу по стандартизации С++](https://stdcpp.ru/)

Comment: @user7860670 я уже нашёл [подобное предложение](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0506r2.pdf), но не могу отследить его судьбу. Оно было ещё в 17 стандарт, но даже в 20 вроде не принято

Comment: std::bitset конструируется  тем же, чем конструируется std::string_view,  какой смысл конструировать  std::string_view,, когда можно сразу конструировать std::bitset. Ведь никакую работу со строкой не выполняется _ она только для инициализации,...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan смысл в том, что при наличии только `std::string_view` не надо выполнять приведение к `std::string` для создания `std::bitset`, а сразу использовать нужный конструктор

Comment: преобразовывать ничего не нужно, нужно лишь брать строковое представление, вызвав std::string_view::data, но  в основном доступно то, чем конструировался сам std::string_view:, а  для редких случаев... Вы представляете что будет, если , стараться удовлетворять потребности всех программистов для каждого случая? Стандарт дает удобные инструменты, чтобы вам было удобно  выполнять работу, но он не может разбухать коды ради каких то редких потребностей....  Наверняка считается, что все таки такие потребности не являются частыми. Лично я  так считаю....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `std::string_view::data()` не возвращает `std::string`. Это не редкая потребность, а основной смысл `std::string_view`: не передавать `std::string` по константной ссылке

Comment: Стоп. std::string_view::data() возвращает const char* (  Я говорил о строковом представлении,) чем можно  конструировать  std::bitset.  А почему и когда используется  std::string_view, я прекрасно знаю, вот только начинаю сомневаться, что вы  хорошо представляете  для чего , и когда  его использовать

Comment: @ARHovsepyan действительно, можно использовать `const char*` конструктор `std::bitset`, но вопрос был в другом. У меня есть функция, в которую передаётся `std::string_view`, а в этой функции надо создать `std::bitset`. Без вызова `std::string_view::data()`, преобразования в `std::string` или других метаморфоз этого сделать нельзя. Вот я и спрашиваю почему

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109305/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-0x25).